# W-4 withholding options limited according to ADP

Tags: united-states, withholding, payroll-taxes, form-w-4

My employer recently switched to ADP for payroll and I want to select 'Married, but withhold at the higher single rate' for my W-4.

That option isn't available on their ADP portal. And according to the ADP consultants (not since if they're independent or part of ADP), they only offer 'Married' and 'Single'.

I'm not a tax lawyer, but aren't all payroll services legally obligated to provide the same options as what's listed on the W-4??

Comment: Do they just mean via the portal they don't support it? Seems unlikely that they disregard W-4's.

Comment: Yes, via their portal.

Comment: You really need an option for "I'm really married, but want you to pretend that I'm a married person pretending to be single"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't (and generally this site won't) comment on what ADP must legally do, although they're a rather large company so I'd be surprised if they are violating the law.  At any rate, you can fill out your W4 using the `Single` option.  All the W4 is used for is to calculate how much to withhold from each pay period, it doesn't affect how you file your taxes at all.  So you can pick the `Single` option, as that's the same as `Married, but withhold at the higher single rate`.